# How to compile MPI with gcc?

Tags: gcc, mpi

Does anyone know if it is possible to compile MPI with `gcc`?. I need to use `gcc`, no `mpicc`.

Comment: It's possible but why do you want to? Normally, the wrapped compiler (mpicc here) is much more convenient and will have been optimised in some way.

Comment: for cmake you should not use the wrapper [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-June/045037.html), because CMake figures out how to compile MPI programs without it.) just use `find_package(MPI REQUIRED)`. It is much cleaner than a wrapper just to set the link/compile flags

Answer (score 36):

`mpicc` is just a wrapper around certain set of compilers. Most implementations have their `mpicc` wrappers understand a special option like `-showme` (Open MPI) or `-show` (Open MPI, MPICH and derivates) that gives the full list of options that the wrapper passes on to the backend compiler.

For example, in Open MPI, wrappers are C++ programs that read plain text configuration files and build command line options that are further passed on to the compiler. `mpicc -showme` shows the full list of such options:

```
$ mpicc -showme
icc
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/include
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/include/openmpi
-fexceptions
-pthread
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
-Wl,-rpath,/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
-L/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
-lmpi
-ldl
-Wl,--export-dynamic
-lnsl
-lutil
```

(it's really a single line that I have split here to improve readability)

It that particular case Intel C Compiler `icc` is used as the backend compiler but we also have variants that use GCC. You can also get the list of options needed for the comple phase (usually known as `CFLAGS`) with `mpicc -showme:compile`:

```
$ mpicc -showme:compile
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/include
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/include/openmpi
-fexceptions
-pthread
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
```

as well as the list of options that you need to pass to the linker (known as `LDFLAGS`) with `mpicc -showme:link`:

```
$ mpicc -showme:link
-fexceptions
-pthread
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
-Wl,-rpath,/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
-I/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
-L/opt/MPI/openmpi-1.5.3/linux/intel/lib
-lmpi
-ldl
-Wl,--export-dynamic
-lnsl
-lutil
```

These could be used, e.g. in a `Makefile`, like this:

```
...
CFLAGS += $(shell mpicc -showme:compile)
LDFLAGS += $(shell mpicc -showme:link)
...
```

As far as I know `-showme:compile` and `-showme:link` are specific to Open MPI and other implementations only give the full list of options when called with `-show`.

I still think it's better to use `mpicc` directly because if it happens that something in the MPI setup is changed, it will be immediately reflected in the wrapper while you would have to change your build script / `Makefile` manually (unless you use `-showme:compile` and `-showme:link` to obtain the options automatically).

Answer (score 8):

`mpicc -compile_info` for MPICH.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use gcc actually. But in my case (on Ubuntu) mpicc is just a wrapper of gcc, here is the output of command `mpicc -showme`:

```
gcc -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2021/libevent -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2021/libevent/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi
```

While in [Open MPI docs](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps):

> The Open MPI team strongly recommends that you simply use Open MPI's "wrapper" compilers to compile your MPI applications. That is, instead of using (for example) gcc to compile your program, use mpicc.
>
> We repeat the above statement: the Open MPI Team strongly recommends that the use the wrapper compilers to compile and link MPI applications.
> If you find yourself saying, "But I don't want to use wrapper compilers!", please humor us and try them. See if they work for you. Be sure to let us know if they do not work for you.
> Many people base their "wrapper compilers suck!" mentality on bad behavior from poorly-implemented wrapper compilers in the mid-1990's. Things are much better these days; wrapper compilers can handle almost any situation, and are far more reliable than you attempting to hard-code the Open MPI-specific compiler and linker flags manually.
> That being said, there are some -- very, very few -- situations where using wrapper compilers can be problematic -- such as nesting multiple wrapper compilers of multiple projects. Hence, Open MPI provides a workaround to find out what command line flags you need to compile MPI applications.

Here this answer is useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

For MPICH, according to the mpicc man pages, `mpicc -compile_info` shows the flags for compiling a program, and `mpicc -link_info` shows the flags for linking a program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly compile an MPI program without the convenience of the `mpicc` wrapper.  On most implementations `mpicc` is a shell script (or similar) which sets environment variables, finds and links various libraries, all the sort of stuff that you might otherwise put into a Makefile.

I suggest that you find an instance of the `mpicc` script and deconstruct it.

Answer (score 0):

`mpicc` is already using `gcc` as a backend